# Clang ThreadSanitizer: unlock of an unlocked mutex, and an atomic is creating a data-race

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, thread-sanitizer

I'm thread-analyzing using ThreadSanitizer, and I'm getting a warning that's very, very confusing to my understanding on how mutexes work. I'm using gcc 6.3 on Debian Stretch.

In a class, at one thread, I have:

```
auto MyPtr = std::make_shared<MyClass>(...);
```

At another place that's called by another thread, I have:

```
if(MyPtr.get()) {...}
```

ThreadSanitizer warned me about a race condition, which is great. So I fixed this by the following:

```
std::unique_lock<decltype(MyMutex)> lg(MyMutex); //MyMutex is std::mutex
auto MyPtr = std::make_shared<...>(...);
lg.unlock();
```

And the other spot:

```
std::unique_lock<decltype(MyMutex)> lg(MyMutex);
if(MyPtr.get()) {...}
// mutex unlocks at the end of the function, which is like after another if-condition.
```

Now the data race is gone, and ThreadSanitizer says that the Mutex is being unlocked "twice"...

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: unlock of an unlocked mutex (or by a wrong thread)
```

and it's pointing to the `unlock()` call + the end of the other function.

**How could a mutex be unlocked twice?** Could someone explain?

Now Since this gave me this headache, I decided to do this instead:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> MyPtr; //in the class definition
std::atomic_store(&MyPtr, std::make_shared<MyClass>(...));
```

And now I get a data-race complaint:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race
```

So am I using ThreadSanitizer wrong? Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Try `std::lock_guard`. You might want to post a [mcve], because without seeing the complete code, (at least) I am unable to figure out why ThreadSanitizer complains (it depends on a lot of stuff, which you haven't mentioned in your description, that's why code is better than text IMO)

Comment: How is your second thread getting access to `MyPtr`? There seems to me a possibility that `MyPtr` goes out to scope in the first thread (thus destroying the pointee) before the second gets to run - but there's not enough code to be sure.   

Thread 2 needs to ensure it has a copy of MyPtr for its lifetime - easiest way is to copy-by-capture in a lambda. You'd usually do this with a `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm unable to create the minimal example... I tried and failed for like 30 minutes. It doesn't create the problem.

Comment: @marko It's a member of the same class that has both methods.

Comment: Also worth noting - `std::shared_ptr` offers some thread-safety guarantees - particularly around any operation that modifies the reference count.  It is therefore always safe to copy or release a reference to a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @marko True, but it's not thread-safe to use `operator=` from another `shared_ptr`, AFAIK. The thread-safety is offered with an atomic reference counter only.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Ok. Let's frame it another way: is an object of your class guaranteed to exist as long as the thread that subsequently uses `MyPtr`?  The use of a mutex to protect your data doesn't help here as it got deleted as well with the object.

Comment: @marko Good question. Let me play around with shared_ptr instances to make sure that's the case.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist if that were true, the other thread safety guarantees are essentially useless.  The pointee of the `shared_ptr` on the rhs of the expression safely gains an extra reference - notionally owned by the lhs.    The pointee on the LHS safety looses a reference (potentially getting deleted).   The assumption here is that the shared_ptr isn't deleted beneath you - but that's an entirely different kind problem - and possibly the one that's pertinent to you here.

Could you post a more complete code sample so we can see what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @marko That's actually very, very difficult. The program is huge. I'm still thinking of a way to do this.

Comment: @marko By making the other load atomic the problem was solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never figured out the mutex problem, but I was able to get rid of the data race with atomics by making the other load atomic:

```
if(std::atomic_load(&MyPtr).get()) {...}
```

Comment: Be careful relying on that result later, because you aren't keeping the the `shared_ptr` returned by `atomic_load` around, it can still get invalidated at any point. If you are using that pointer at all, keep the `shared_ptr` around